# Запись некорректных значений в переменную типа enum или enum class

Tags: c++, c, enum, enum-class, static-cast

Подскажите, пожалуйста, позволяют ли правила языков `C` и `C++` записывать в переменную типа `enum` или `enum class` некорректное значение?

В найденных мной источниках данный вопрос раскрывается недостаточно ясно.

Вот что написано в стандарте:

> 9) A value of a scoped enumeration type (10.2) can be explicitly
>   converted to an integral type. When that type is cv bool, the
>   resulting value is false if the original value is zero and true for
>   all other values. For the remaining integral types, the value is
>   unchanged if the original value can be represented by the specified
>   type. Otherwise, the resulting value is unspecified. A value of a
>   scoped enumeration type can also be explicitly converted to a
>   floating-point type; the result is the same as that of converting from
>   the original value to the floating-point type.
>
> 10) A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted
>   to a complete enumeration type. If the enumeration type has a fixed
>   underlying type, the value is first converted to that type by integral
>   conversion, if necessary, and then to the enumeration type. If the
>   enumeration type does not have a fixed underlying type, the value is
>   unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration
>   values (10.2), and otherwise, the behavior is undefined. A value of
>   floating-point type can also be explicitly converted to an enumeration
>   type. The resulting value is the same as converting the original value
>   to the underlying type of the enumeration (7.10), and subsequently to
>   the enumeration type.

Написанное здесь я понимаю так:

```
const uint32_t value = 257;

enum class A
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO,
    THREE
};
const A a = const_cast<A>(value);// Undefined behavior

enum class B : uint8_t
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO,
    THREE
};
const B b = const_cast<B>(value);// Unspecified behavior

enum class C : uint32_t
{
    ONE = 1,
    TWO,
    THREE
};
const C c = static_cast<C>(value);// OK
```

Я прав? И если нет, то в чем я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106030/discussion-on-question-by-mgneo-------e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **10.2 Enumeration declarations [dcl.enum]**
>   8 For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. Otherwise, for an enumeration where e min is the smallest enumerator and e max is the largest, the values of the enumeration are the values in the range b min to b max , defined as follows: Let K be 1 for a two’s complement representation and 0 for a ones’ complement or sign-magnitude representation. b max
>   is the smallest value greater than or equal to max ( |e min | − K,|e max | ) and equal to 2 M − 1, where M is a non-negative integer. b min is zero if e min is non-negative and − ( b max + K ) otherwise. The size of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is max(M,1) if b min is zero and M + 1 otherwise. It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators. If the enumerator-list is empty, the values of the enumeration are as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

1. когда нижележащий целочисленный тип енумератора задан явно, то в переменную можно записывать любое значение этого целочисленного типа:

```
enum t_Value: int {};
t_Value value{static_cast<t_Value>(42)}; // ОК (любое значение int)
```

2. когда нижележащий целочисленный тип енумератора не задан, то в переменную можно записывать значения, которые попадают в диапазон значений, которые можно хранить в битовом поле, которое будет достаточно для хранение всех указанных значений енумератора:

```
enum t_Value{ alp = 0, bet = 1, gam = 2, del = 3, eps = 4 }; // требует 3 бита
t_Value value0{static_cast<t_Value>(0)}; // OK 000
t_Value value1{static_cast<t_Value>(1)}; // OK 001
t_Value value2{static_cast<t_Value>(2)}; // OK 010
t_Value value3{static_cast<t_Value>(3)}; // OK 011
t_Value value4{static_cast<t_Value>(4)}; // OK 100
t_Value value5{static_cast<t_Value>(5)}; // OK 101
t_Value value6{static_cast<t_Value>(6)}; // OK 110
t_Value value7{static_cast<t_Value>(7)}; // OK 111
t_Value value8{static_cast<t_Value>(8)}; // UB, не укладывается в 3 бита
```

3. когда нижележащий целочисленный тип енумератора не задан и не указано ни одного значения, то диапазон значений будет таким же, как если бы было заданно одно значение 0:

```
enum t_Value{}; // требует 1 бит
t_Value value0{static_cast<t_Value>(0)}; // OK 0
t_Value value1{static_cast<t_Value>(1)}; // OK 1
t_Value value2{static_cast<t_Value>(2)}; // UB, не укладывается в 1 бит
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно записать и другие значения underlying type, который по умолчанию, если не указан явно, есть int. Неопределенным это было только в "компиляторах" одной фирмы, которая не следует стандартам, она их создает.

Comment: Любое значение underlying type можно записать, только если он задан явно. А если он не задан, то он может быть и не int.

Comment: @user7860670 ну не совсем так. Underlying type тут будет int, просто не все значения можно записывать, да.